# Passing parameters from C# to Jquery function()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a gridview in the asp.net page. And each column has a button, on the click of which I am opening an Pop up using jquery.

```
 protected void gvExpiry_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
            {
                Button tmp = new Button();
                tmp = ((Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnTest"));
                tmp.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:return MyFunc(" + gvExpiry.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString() + "," + gvExpiry.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString() + ")";

            }
        }



$("[id*=btnTest]").live("click", function () {           
             $("#modal_dialog").dialog({                 
                 close:function(event, ui){                       
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                 },
                 title: "Please enter tag",
                 buttons: {
                     Ok: function MyFunc(fileName, tag) {                        
                         //alert(fileName);
                         var etag = $("#<%= txttag.ClientID  %>").val(); 
                         alert(typeof fileName);
                         alert(typeof Etag)
                         //other functionality
 },
                 modal: true
             });
             return false;
         });
```

But in my MyFunc(fileName, Etag) I'm not getting the correct values of the parameters. I am gettng object and undefined value

How can I get the correct value of my parameters

Comment: try `gvExpiry.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["your_datakeyname"].Value`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding single quotes in the function call, the function thinks the text are variables, not strings.

```
tmp.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:return MyFunc('" + gvExpiry.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString() + "','" + gvExpiry.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString() + "')";
```

Comment: You need to analyze the rendered html and make sure that there are no errors in the script.